# RN4870 / RN4871 forget its configuration settings during power up

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a problem with a couple RN4870 moduls. Sometimes they will forget their configuration settings (MAC address). Microchip told me, that is a power up problem and this issue will be solved with the new firmware version 1.28.3. 
Has anyboby any experience with that firmware?
I don't want to flash all my moduls and the problem still exists, because it's not so easy to connect every single modul to flash the firmware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!
The main reason for the lost data in the module is the power up procedure. After I put a capacitor (10 uF) as close as possible to the power supply pins of the module it works pretty well. This was independently of the firmware version. Hope this info will help somebody else.